# Division rings with any non-zero member of multiplicative order dividing $n$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Let $n>2$ be a natural number and let $D$ be a division ring with the property that for any $d\not = 0$, $d^n =1$. Is there any simple way (not using deep theorems of division rings or Wedderburn's theorem) to deduce that $D$ is commutative !?

Answer (score 1):

(Note: This should really be a comment, but is too long)

This seems like a hard problem, and I did some digging and here is what showed up :

[Jacobson's paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969205) which proves the very surprising result that

> If, for each element $a$ in a ring $R$, there exists an integer $n(a) > 1$ such that $a^{n(a)} = a$, then $R$ is commutative.

The result is deep though : It uses a neat calculation (See Theorem 11) that reduces it to a problem of algebras over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and then uses Wedderburn's theorem (See Theorem 8) to do that case.

There is a much simpler argument due to Forsythe and McCoy (see [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183509414)), which solves this problem when $(n-1)$ is prime. That is elementary once you have seen it, but I suspect even that takes a fair amount of thinking before it pops out.

Comment: Dear Prahlad, As you have mentioned, the problem goes back to Jacobson. But here I think we have a weaker version of the original one: first the ring is a division ring and then $n(a)$ is a fixed natural number that does not depend on $a$. This is why I am hoping for a much simpler argument rather than those that you have mentioned above.

Comment: @user41303 : I thought so too, but the fact that Forsythe/McCoy only treat the prime case makes me inclined to believe that there might not be.

Comment: there would always be a spring